# Remove https: from Api response flutter

Tags: flutter, rest, dart

```js
/*
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final hisselist = hisselistFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Hisselist hisselistFromJson(String str) => Hisselist.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String hisselistToJson(Hisselist data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Hisselist {
  Hisselist({
    required this.success,
    required this.result,
  });

  bool success;
  List<ResultClass> result;

  factory Hisselist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Hisselist(
    success: json["success"], result: json["result"].map<ResultClass>((x) => ResultClass.fromJson(x)).toList(),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "success": success,
    "result": result.map((x) => x.toJson()),
  };
}

class ResultClass {
  ResultClass({
    required this.rate,
    required this.lastprice,
    required this.lastpricestr,
    required this.hacim,
    required this.hacimstr,
    required this.text,
    required this.code,
  });

  double rate;
  double lastprice;
  String lastpricestr;
  double hacim;
  String hacimstr;
  String text;
  String code;

  factory ResultClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ResultClass(
    rate: double.tryParse(json["rate"].toString()) ?? 0.0,
    lastprice: double.tryParse(json["lastprice"].toString()) ?? 0.0,
    lastpricestr: json["lastpricestr"],
    hacim: double.tryParse(json["hacim"].toString()) ?? 0.0,
    hacimstr: json["hacimstr"],
    text: json["text"],
    code: json["code"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "rate": rate,
    "lastprice": lastprice,
    "lastpricestr": lastpricestr,
    "hacim": hacim,
    "hacimstr": hacimstr,
    "text": text,
    "code": code,
  };
}


 */

// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final hisselist = hisselistFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Hisselist hisselistFromJson(String str) => Hisselist.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String hisselistToJson(Hisselist data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Hisselist {
  Hisselist({
    required this.success,
    required this.result,
  });

  bool success;
  List<Result> result;

  factory Hisselist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Hisselist(
    success: json["success"],
    result: List<Result>.from(json["result"].map((x) => Result.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "success": success,
    "result": List<dynamic>.from(result.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Result {
  Result({
    this.rate,
    this.lastprice,
    this.lastpricestr,
    this.hacim,
    this.hacimstr,
    this.min,
    this.minstr,
    this.max,
    this.maxstr,
    this.time,
    this.text,
    this.code,
  });

  double? rate;
  double? lastprice;
  String? lastpricestr;
  String? hacim;
  String? hacimstr;
  dynamic min;
  String? minstr;
  dynamic max;
  String? maxstr;
  Time? time;
  String? text;
  String? code;

  factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Result(
    rate: json["rate"].toDouble(),
    lastprice: json["lastprice"].toDouble(),
    lastpricestr: json["lastpricestr"],
    hacim: json["hacim"],
    hacimstr: json["hacimstr"],
    min: json["min"],
    minstr: json["minstr"],
    max: json["max"],
    maxstr: json["maxstr"],
    time: timeValues.map[json["time"]],
    text: json["text"],
    code: json["code"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "rate": rate,
    "lastprice": lastprice,
    "lastpricestr": lastpricestr,
    "hacim": hacim,
    "hacimstr": hacimstr,
    "min": min,
    "minstr": minstr,
    "max": max,
    "maxstr": maxstr,
    "time": timeValues.reverse[time],
    "text": text,
    "code": code,
  };
}

enum Time { THE_1809, THE_1808, THE_1805, THE_1810, THE_1759, THE_1755 }

final timeValues = EnumValues({
  "17:55": Time.THE_1755,
  "17:59": Time.THE_1759,
  "18:05": Time.THE_1805,
  "18:08": Time.THE_1808,
  "18:09": Time.THE_1809,
  "18:10": Time.THE_1810
});

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String>? reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap!;
  }
}
```

And this is where i call api :

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../models/apis/hisselist.dart';




class Hisseler extends StatefulWidget {
  const Hisseler({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Hisseler> createState() => _HisselerState();
}

class _HisselerState extends State<Hisseler> {

  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final url = Uri.parse('https://api.collectapi.com/economy/hisseSenedi');
  var counter;

  Hisselist? hisseResult;

  Future callHisse() async {
    try{
      Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'apikey 4xxxxP'
      };
      final response = await http.get(url,headers:requestHeaders);

      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        var result = hisselistFromJson(response.body);

        if(mounted);
        setState(() {

          counter = result.result.length;
          result.result.sort((a, b) => (a.text ?? "").compareTo(b.text ?? ""));

          hisseResult = result;
        });
        return result;
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    callHisse();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
            'Hisseler'
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: counter != null ?

          ListView.separated(

              itemCount: counter,

              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Divider(color: Colors.grey[400]);
              },
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    title: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(hisseResult?.result[index].code??"", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                        Text(hisseResult?.result[index].text??"",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500], fontSize: 14))
                      ],
                    ),
                    trailing: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(hisseResult?.result[index].lastpricestr??"", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                        Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                color: Colors.red
                            ),
                            width: 75,
                            height: 25,
                            child: Text(hisseResult?.result[index].rate.toString()??"",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                ),);
              }) : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(

          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the result i get:
[image]

as you see here, code response start with "https:" i don't want to show this "https:" part from response. How i can fix this?
Thanks for your help

Comment: You can try to use: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/replaceAll.html

Comment: @MendelG I can also use substring but I couldn't manage to do it. Can you show me a code example, please?

Comment: What line of your code is responsible for printing the "https"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems the "https:" comes emberded in your API data, therefore we need to replace that string from the variable code.

Replace the Text code with this:

```
Text((hisseResult?.result[index].code ?? "")
                    .replaceAll("https:", ""),
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500))
```

Comment: Can you explain me please why hisseResult?.result[index].code??"".substring(6) is not working?

Comment: .substring(index) depends on the length of your string, if your string is less than the index, then you get an error. To use it you need to chech the length of the string first, then get the subtring. It is easier to just replace the string you dont want, because it works if it exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
hisseResult?.result[index].code?.substring(5)
```

null safety fix also added

- subString changed into substring

Comment: to use substring we must check the length of the string first, that's why substring not working here. Check the answer of Allan Mitre. 
If you add a check to the length of the string to this answer, it will be also a correct answer. But using replace is more logical it seems

Comment: If you add ? before substring, there is no error and it works