# Change color if api response is positive flutter

Tags: flutter, rest, dart

```js
/*
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final hisselist = hisselistFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Hisselist hisselistFromJson(String str) => Hisselist.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String hisselistToJson(Hisselist data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Hisselist {
  Hisselist({
    required this.success,
    required this.result,
  });

  bool success;
  List<ResultClass> result;

  factory Hisselist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Hisselist(
    success: json["success"], result: json["result"].map<ResultClass>((x) => ResultClass.fromJson(x)).toList(),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "success": success,
    "result": result.map((x) => x.toJson()),
  };
}

class ResultClass {
  ResultClass({
    required this.rate,
    required this.lastprice,
    required this.lastpricestr,
    required this.hacim,
    required this.hacimstr,
    required this.text,
    required this.code,
  });

  double rate;
  double lastprice;
  String lastpricestr;
  double hacim;
  String hacimstr;
  String text;
  String code;

  factory ResultClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ResultClass(
    rate: double.tryParse(json["rate"].toString()) ?? 0.0,
    lastprice: double.tryParse(json["lastprice"].toString()) ?? 0.0,
    lastpricestr: json["lastpricestr"],
    hacim: double.tryParse(json["hacim"].toString()) ?? 0.0,
    hacimstr: json["hacimstr"],
    text: json["text"],
    code: json["code"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "rate": rate,
    "lastprice": lastprice,
    "lastpricestr": lastpricestr,
    "hacim": hacim,
    "hacimstr": hacimstr,
    "text": text,
    "code": code,
  };
}


 */

// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final hisselist = hisselistFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Hisselist hisselistFromJson(String str) => Hisselist.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String hisselistToJson(Hisselist data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Hisselist {
  Hisselist({
    required this.success,
    required this.result,
  });

  bool success;
  List<Result> result;

  factory Hisselist.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Hisselist(
    success: json["success"],
    result: List<Result>.from(json["result"].map((x) => Result.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "success": success,
    "result": List<dynamic>.from(result.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Result {
  Result({
    this.rate,
    this.lastprice,
    this.lastpricestr,
    this.hacim,
    this.hacimstr,
    this.min,
    this.minstr,
    this.max,
    this.maxstr,
    this.time,
    this.text,
    this.code,
  });

  double? rate;
  double? lastprice;
  String? lastpricestr;
  String? hacim;
  String? hacimstr;
  dynamic min;
  String? minstr;
  dynamic max;
  String? maxstr;
  Time? time;
  String? text;
  String? code;

  factory Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Result(
    rate: json["rate"].toDouble(),
    lastprice: json["lastprice"].toDouble(),
    lastpricestr: json["lastpricestr"],
    hacim: json["hacim"],
    hacimstr: json["hacimstr"],
    min: json["min"],
    minstr: json["minstr"],
    max: json["max"],
    maxstr: json["maxstr"],
    time: timeValues.map[json["time"]],
    text: json["text"],
    code: json["code"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "rate": rate,
    "lastprice": lastprice,
    "lastpricestr": lastpricestr,
    "hacim": hacim,
    "hacimstr": hacimstr,
    "min": min,
    "minstr": minstr,
    "max": max,
    "maxstr": maxstr,
    "time": timeValues.reverse[time],
    "text": text,
    "code": code,
  };
}

enum Time { THE_1809, THE_1808, THE_1805, THE_1810, THE_1759, THE_1755 }

final timeValues = EnumValues({
  "17:55": Time.THE_1755,
  "17:59": Time.THE_1759,
  "18:05": Time.THE_1805,
  "18:08": Time.THE_1808,
  "18:09": Time.THE_1809,
  "18:10": Time.THE_1810
});

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String>? reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap!;
  }
}
```

And this is where i call api :

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import '../models/apis/hisselist.dart';




class Hisseler extends StatefulWidget {
  const Hisseler({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Hisseler> createState() => _HisselerState();
}

class _HisselerState extends State<Hisseler> {

  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final url = Uri.parse('https://api.collectapi.com/economy/hisseSenedi');
  var counter;

  Hisselist? hisseResult;

  Future callHisse() async {
    try{
      Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'apikey 4xxxxP'
      };
      final response = await http.get(url,headers:requestHeaders);

      if(response.statusCode == 200){
        var result = hisselistFromJson(response.body);

        if(mounted);
        setState(() {

          counter = result.result.length;
          result.result.sort((a, b) => (a.text ?? "").compareTo(b.text ?? ""));

          hisseResult = result;
        });
        return result;
      } else {
        print(response.statusCode);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    callHisse();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: false,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text(
            'Hisseler'
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: counter != null ?

          ListView.separated(

              itemCount: counter,

              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Divider(color: Colors.grey[400]);
              },
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return Card(
                  child: ListTile(
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    title: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(hisseResult?.result[index].code??"", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                        Text(hisseResult?.result[index].text??"",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500], fontSize: 14))
                      ],
                    ),
                    trailing: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(hisseResult?.result[index].lastpricestr??"", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500)),
                        Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                                color: Colors.red
                            ),
                            width: 75,
                            height: 25,
                            child: Text(hisseResult?.result[index].rate.toString()??"",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                ),);
              }) : Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(

          )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the result i get:
[image]

as you see here, rate result can be negative or positive.  I want to make the red color green if the value is green. how can I do this?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your container with this code:

```
Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
            color: (hisseResult?.result[index].rate ?? 0) > 0
                ? Colors.green
                : Colors.red),
        width: 75,
        height: 25,
        child: Text(hisseResult?.result[index].rate.toString() ?? "",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)))
```

if rate > 0, the container is set to green, else container is set to red

Greetings!

Comment: Works thank you! can you check this too please, i couldn't manage to use substring here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73438887/remove-https-from-api-response-flutter

Answer (score 1):

Flutter allows **conditions when giving values to widgets atributes.**

Just use a ternary operator which is very clean visual and suits this perfectly:

```
color:  hisseResult?.result[index].rate > 0 ? Colors.green : Colors.red,
```

Selamlar :)

Comment: I tried this before but i get this error : error: The operator '>' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. couldnt manage to null-safety. Aleykümselam :)

Comment: You can force null on it with the use of  exclamation mark '!'

It seems to me that when you get there, you always have results, other wise the CircularProgressIndicator would appear instead, or am I missing something?

Comment: "result[index].rate ??" fixes the problem. you can check Allan Mitre's answer in this topic.

Comment: by the way do you have any idea how can i use substring here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73438887/remove-https-from-api-response-flutter